# make how to replace the last characters for the Notepad ++

Tags: xml, notepad++

Please help, I have a lot of code in the xml file I want to replace the last word

```
<Meaning>sự hạ thủy (tàu, thuyền); sự phóng (tên lửa)</para>
```

into

```
<Meaning>sự hạ thủy (tàu, thuyền); sự phóng (tên lửa)</Meaning>
```

I used the following replacement code:
Find what:

```
^<Meaning>(.*)\<+.*$
```

Replace with:

```
/<Meaning>$1.</Meaning>
```

But when the result returns "find: invalid regular expression"

Comment: You want to replace just </para> with </Meaning>?

Comment: No, there is a lot of code in the xml file, but I just want to replace the lines that are "<Meaning>" and the last one is "</ para>" to <Meaning> * < / Meaning>
Please help!

Comment: In the xml file there are many lines:

<Meaning> launch (ship, boat); launch (rocket) </ para>
  <Altitude altitude (rocket launcher) </ para>

But only want to replace all the lines:

<Meaning> launch (ship, boat); launch (rocket) </ para>

to:

<Meaning> launch (ship, boat); launch (rocket) </ span>

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need a regex that matches only the part you want to replace. If I understood you right, you want to replace `</ para>` if there is no other tag than `<Meaning>` before it.
This would be a perfect case for positiv lookbehinds, but as they are limited to a fixed number of characters we need to use `\K`.

So search for `<Meaning>`, search for anything that is not a tag, throw it all away with `\K` and get `<\ para>`

**regex**:

```
<Meaning>[^<]*[^>]*\K</ para>
```

maybe you want to be sure, that `</ para>` is the last piece of text in the line. You can search for linebreaks `\n\r` (and optional whitespaces `\s`) but you don't want it to be replaced so wrap it with `(?= )`

```
<Meaning>[^<]*[^>]*\K</ para>(?=\s*[\n\r])
```

If you want to be sure, that `<Meaning>` is the first piece in the line you have to check either the start of the document `^` or a linebrake `[\r\n]`

```
(?:^|[\r\n])<Meaning>[^<]*[^>]*\K</ para>(?=\s*[\n\r])
```

Maybe I got you wrong and there can be anything between `<Meaning>` and `</ para>` unless it's in the same line. In that case you can use:

```
(?:^|[\r\n])<Meaning>[^\n\r]*\K</ para>(?=\s*[\n\r])
```